# Determining if HTML Input element is checked in C#

Tags: c#, html

Part of an application I'm working on needs to tell which of a group of radio buttons on a web page is checked. The code I've written so far doesn't work:

```
foreach(HtmlElement element in thgBrowser.Document.All)
{
   if (element.Name == "Category" && element.GetAttribute("checked") == "checked")
      return element.GetAttribute("value");
}
```

From what I understand, even though "checked" is boolean, the attribute is set as checked or checked="checked". Because of this, I get an error when I attempt

```
...GetAttribute("checked") == true
```

I've tried two other ways of doing this, both of which failed. I tried:

```
...GetAttribute("checked") != null
```

which made it so I always got the value of the first radio button in the group regardless of which one was selected. The other failed way of doing this is in the original code snippet, where I use:

```
...GetAttribute("checked") == "checked"
```

This made it so none of the buttons were recognized as being checked. Does anyone know a way I can do this?

Comment: I don't understand -- you say C# but this looks like JavaScript to me.  What is going on?

Comment: @Hogan this is clearly c#

Comment: I haven't done DOM in C# for a long time, but you could try `element.GetAttribute("checked") == ""`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) returns string.

If element has `checked` attribute, method will return `True`; will return `False` otherwise.

You could do two things:

Parse the string

```
if (element.Name == "Category" && Convert.ToBoolean(element.GetAttribute("checked"))
    return element.GetAttribute("value");
```

or compare it with Boolean string

```
if (element.Name == "Category" && element.GetAttribute("checked") == bool.TrueString)
    return element.GetAttribute("value");
```